Existentialism is real, so why does Russell's paradox matter?
"This statement is false."
It certainly looks like a truth-functional statement! So is it true or false?
The true answer is: It doesn’t matter.
If Bertrand Russell has trouble sleeping because he knows a barber will shave everyone who doesn't shave himself that night, then he might as well have slept. Because come sunrise, the barber either did or did not shave himself. THAT’S ALL THERE IS.
What there isn't, is a "paradox." There isn't anything but a barber. His chin might have hair on it. Everything else is make-believe.
Existence not only precedes essence, existence IS essence. Again, there ISN’T anything else.
Einstein’s buddy Kurt did some work so clever that it makes me giggle with delight. But all Godel proved was that it’s possible for intelligent animals to use infinite recursion to construct incomplete formal systems.
So what?
Godel and Russell might as well have saved time, cut out the middle man, and just asserted:
FALSE = TRUE.
Then you and I and all the other computer science nerds can sit in a dorm room marveling at this amaaazing paradox while all the “stupid” kids have fun.
I was surprised when I learned that existentialism has a name. It’s so obviously true that it never occurred to me that anyone would even think about it, much less disagree with it.
My question about Russell is equivalent to the following one:
Why is Godel's incompleteness theorem important when it only shows incompleteness in pathological unterminated recursion, but not otherwise?
It seems perfectly legitimate to assert: other than that, arithmetic is complete. Furthermore, the incompleteness theorem doesn't really appear to be useful.
And don't get me started on the halting problem.

Take a look at my article explaining the causes of Russell's paradox and the hidden paradoxes of Godel's incompleteness theorem. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/377571704_Turing_Machine_Halting_Problem_Russell's_Paradox_and_Godel_Incompleteness_Theorem

A very impressive article indeed! But I got two things out of it. 1: You conclude that Russell's paradox is invalid because it involves a circular argument, since set membership is not well defined. And 2: You agree withb Wittgenstein that,  "'Mathematical  propositions,  like  other propositions, do need to explain their grammar' That is, we must regulate and restrict mathematical propositions such as Russell’s Paradox and the Gödel formula." Sounds like you, me, and Wittgenstein all agree!

You seem to be using existentialism in some sort of ontological sense, so the usual sense of existentialism can be found here. As for Russell's paradox, no one is claiming the words cause some sort of indeterminancy in the state of affairs. Rather, paradoxes are more like math problems that end with a result like 0=1, which is a non-sensical result. That means there's a problem with the logic system, and logicians can't accept that any more than math folks can accept 1=0. How to interpret these errors is the stuff of philosophy.

-1 This question seems more like a rant or a chance to blow-off steam.

It seems like you've packed a couple of questions into one. The question "why does Russell's paradox matter?" is an interesting question with an interesting answer, and the question "why do Gödel's incompleteness theorems matter?" is a different interesting question with a different interesting answer.

For what it's worth, I don't know of anyone who spends time sitting in a dorm room marveling at Russell's paradox, but I know of lots of people who spend time building systems that have useful applications in the real world, and who take care to ensure that their systems don't fall afoul of Russel's paradox, because the systems would become useless if they did.

I'm sure that if we asked you about the Halting Problem, we would never hear the end of it :-)

@Miss_Understands I strongly agree with Wittgenstein's idea that ZFC axiomatic set theory is the result of this, thus avoiding Russell's paradox. In the same way, for the science of mathematical logic, we have to set limits, otherwise paradoxes will appear, such as Godel's formula, as I have already pointed out in my article.

Russell's Paradox is of concern to Mathematical Foundations. The barber idea, is just an analogy for laypeople, and completely irrelevent to the signifance of Russell's Paradox.
Frege believed that overlayed over first order logic, a collection of objects satisfying a property- constituded a set.
This was expressed in the Unrestricted Axiom of Comprehnsion.
Which says, essentially, that {x | φ(x)} is a set. For any well-formed formula φ
Russell's Paradox produced an example, φ(x) = x∉x
For which if we permit a set  R = { x | x∉x } then we get that R is both an element of R and not an element of R.
Which, is a problem because if our first order logic proof system can derive x and not x, it can derive anything. Which makes the whole system trivial.
Russell's Result is actually much more powerful than just being a result about the unsuitability of Freges Axiom.
The main idea, appears elsewhere in more "practical" proofs.
Prior to Russell we have the following argument
Theorem ( Cantor's Diagonal Argument)
Let f be a function with domain A, then D = { x∈A | x∉f(x)}∉range(f)
Proof:
Consider an arbitrary pair (a,b) in f, i.e. f(a) = b
We prove that b ≠ D
Case 1: a∈b
As f(a) = b, a∈f(a)
Thus a∉D so D ≠ b
Case 2: a∉b
a∉f(a), so a∈D
Thus D ≠ b
As f, and (a,b) were arbitrarily chosen, we have that f(a) ≠ D for any pair (a,b), and any function f.
So D is not in the range of any function.
also, If the function happened to be the empty function, vacuously it has no elements in its range.
So, Russell's Paradox is really a special case of Cantors Diagonal Argument- which is a very deep argument appearing in many important Theorems across the Mathematical Literature.
Most famous are that the Reals are uncountable, and That the Powerset of a Set, has larger cardinality than the set itelf.
These are core, foundational results in Mathemaics and all share the same basic idea, as Russell's Paradox. - Construct a "Diagonal" Set.
Note: Gödel's Incompleteness is important for Mathematicians because it is by consensus that infinite recursive constructions are the domain in which they work. They consider such a playground, ideal for mathematics.
It's also the case that anything provable in weaker settings, is also provable in the more abstract setting- so they don't lose strength.
Mathematics has a long history of increasing it's degree of abstraction, going into the infinite- is an extention of that.
If we go by Leibnitz and Cantor's approach, then mathematics should be free. As long as we don't produce contradictions and are as precise as possible ( only defining terms out of known terms and primitives).
There was a time when people considered i*i = -1 to be pathological, now we know how to construct i using just cartesian coordinates, and basic operators defined from addition and multiplication of reals.
Furthermore, Mathematicians work under notions of structure, rigor, and creativity. As Cantor's paradise has plenty of it. Unless independence results become too intolerable or an inconsistency appears - I don't see it changing anytime soon.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The Turing Machine Halting Problem is a major problem in computer theory, Russell’s Paradox is the root of the Third Mathematical Crisis, and the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem is a major discovery in modern logic. The three have had a profound impact on the development of science and have attracted the attention of scientific and philosophical circles. However, since the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem was put forward, the scientific and philosophical significance of its proof has been questioned; in particular, Wittgenstein regards it as a certain logical paradox, and Russell’s Paradox has not yet been settled. This paper makes a detailed analysis of the three based on the view of dialectical infinity. The author notes that the Principle of Comprehension based on the view of actual infinity is the root of Russell’s Paradox. The Turing Machine Halting Problem shows that it is impossible to make an actual-infinite ultimate judgment of the constantly generated infinite world, but the philosophical significance of the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem is that our understanding of the world is essentially potentially infinite. At the end of the article, the author raises several questions about the proof of the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem, finds out the specific paradox form in the proof, points out the high consistency of its proof method and Russell’s Paradox, which strongly supports Wittgenstein’s view. The author points out that the philosophical basis of the proof of the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem is the idea of actual infinity, the proof of the theorem is based on a logically invalid circular formula, the contradiction of the proof originates from the Gödel formula itself, and cannot be attributed to the incompleteness of the system, so the proof is wrong. Therefore, the conclusion of this paper is that the world is constantly developing and changing, and our human understanding of the world is essentially a potential infinite, that is, the world is Aristotelian, not Platonic.

You've just pasted the abstract of your article verbatim. But even in the article, you seem to agree with Wittgenstein that Russell's paradox is a contradictory anomaly that shouldn't be allowed to disrupt mathematics.
